# Insertar registros de un archivo TXT a una tabla Fox Pro con C#

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro

Estoy tratando de realizar un programa con C# que tiene el objetivo de leer un archivo TXT e insertarlos a una tabla Fox Pro. Ya logré insertar un registro pero solo lo he podido hacer con la primera línea, mi duda es ¿cómo podría hacer para recorrer línea por línea e insertarlo en la tabla? Por el momento establecí `partes[0]`, `partes[1]` .... hasta el `Partes[4]` que solo me trae los valores de la primera línea y que se repite de acuerdo a la cantidad de líneas que hay en el txt, además considerar que cada línea tiene 5 datos separados por un "|" .

Mi archivo de texto contiene en total dos líneas que deben ser insertadas y son las siguientes:

**Alerta_MantenimMecanicoG1**|**Aviso N° 10003 el CS_VIQMEL -AUSVN /n /n Area: PLTXT /n /n Equipo: CS_VIQMEL- EQUNR +” - ”+ EQKTX /n /n Trabajo: QMARTX /n /n Servicio: CS_VIQMEL -INGRP+” - ”+ INNAM /n /n Solicitante: SNAME /n /n Prioridad: PRIOKX /n /n Descripción Aviso: CS_VIQMEL- QMTXT**|**03/11/2022**|**16:51:32**|**PENDIENTE**

**Alerta_MantenimMecanicoG1**|**Aviso N° 20003 el CS_VIQMEL -AUSVN /n /n Area: PLTXT /n /n Equipo: CS_VIQMEL- EQUNR +” - ”+ EQKTX /n /n Trabajo: QMARTX /n /n Servicio: CS_VIQMEL -INGRP+” - ”+ INNAM /n /n Solicitante: SNAME /n /n Prioridad: PRIOKX /n /n Descripción Aviso: CS_VIQMEL- QMTXT**|**03/11/2022**|**16:51:32**|**PENDIENTE**

Tabla FoxPro:
Como pueden ver en la tabla logré realizar la inserción pero solo es la primera línea la que se inserto y además se repite por segunda vez, no me trae el **aviso N"20003"**

[image: Tabla Fox PrO]

El código C# que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace LeerArchivoParaEnviar
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            string sBase = @"C:\Users\hcardenas\Desktop\DBF\Envio_Wh.DBF";
            string sConn = "Provider = VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(sBase) + ";";

            using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConn))
            {
                try
                {
                    dbConn.ConnectionString = sConn;
                    dbConn.Open();

                    //Inserta los datos
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Envio_Wh (User_Grupo,Mensaje,Fecha,Hora,Estado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", dbConn))
                    {
                        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\MensajesxEnviarWsap2.txt");
                        

                        foreach (string line in lines)
                        {
                            string[] partes = line.Split('|');
                            Console.WriteLine(line);


                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserGrupo", partes[0]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mensaje", partes[1]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", partes[2]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", partes[3]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", partes[4]);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }                      
                    }
                    dbConn.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No se pudo Realizar la insercion", ex);
                }

              
            }

            System.Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que la lista de parámetros necesita estar limpia por cada ExecuteNonQuery. Propongo 2 opciones

1 Tendrías que limpiar la lista de parámetros antes de volver a realizar un add. Me imagino algo así, no se si exista esta instrucción para OleDbCommand.

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserGrupo", partes[0]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mensaje", partes[1]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", partes[2]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", partes[3]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", partes[4]);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

La otra es que declares a cmd como new en cada iteración del foreach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace LeerArchivoParaEnviar
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            string sBase = @"C:\Users\hcardenas\Desktop\DBF\Envio_Wh.DBF";
            string sConn = "Provider = VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(sBase) + ";";

            using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConn))
            {
                try
                {
                    dbConn.ConnectionString = sConn;
                    dbConn.Open();

                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\MensajesxEnviarWsap2.txt");
                    
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        string[] partes = line.Split('|');
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        //Inserta los datos
                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Envio_Wh (User_Grupo,Mensaje,Fecha,Hora,Estado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", dbConn))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserGrupo", partes[0]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mensaje", partes[1]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", partes[2]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", partes[3]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", partes[4]);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }                      
                    dbConn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No se pudo Realizar la insercion", ex);
                }
            }
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial Miguel era eso , solo tenia que colocar el "cmd.Parameters.Clear();" para que puedan ingresarse cada uno de los registros en la tabla FoxPro , gracias por tu tiempo de poder ver mi caso. Éxitos!